# Remove Done button from application apk installer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-install-apk

Is it possible to remove or disable `Done` button which comes when any application is installed. I want that the user must open my application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  That's the play store, its a separate application you have no control over.  Besides, the user may not want to immediately open your app (I tend to download several in the background and open them later).  Why should he be forced to?

Comment: But if my application is installed directly by the apk provided by me then it is installed through package installer. And after installation an android activity is opened saying 'Application installed'. is there any way to disable or remove that done button so that user have only one option i.e. 'open'